# How to locate Sqlpackage tool after global installation in Docker container?

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, dockerfile, sqlpackage

I'm attempting (relatively inexperienced) to write a Dockerfile that publishes a dacpac to a linux container before firing up sqlserver, but building the Dockerfile always results in the following: `/bin/sh: 1: /home/mssql/localtools/sqlpackage: not found`

below is a snippet of my Dockerfile (omitted some boilerplate for brevity)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest AS base

build/publish etc
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4025156&view=sql-server-ver16
RUN dotnet tool install --tool-path ~/localtools microsoft.sqlpackage
#RUN dotnet tool install -g microsoft.sqlpackage

ARG CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "SomeName.Database.sqlproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /db/build -v diag

FROM base AS final
COPY --from=build "/db/build/SomeName.Database.dacpac" "/tmp/SomeName.Database.dacpac"

# Launch SQL Server, confirm startup is complete, deploy the DACPAC, then terminate SQL Server.
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51589787/488695
RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && ( echo "SQLServer started" && sleep 10s ) || ( echo "SQLSERVER failed to start" && exit )

RUN ~/localtools/sqlpackage \
    /Action:Publish \
    /TargetServerName:. \
    /TargetDatabaseName:SomeNameDB \
    /TargetUser:sa \
    /TargetPassword:$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD \
    /SourceFile:/tmp/SomeName.Database.dacpac \
    && pkill sqlservr
```

I've tried specifying the local tools path via `dotnet tool install --tool-path ~/localtools microsoft.sqlpackage` but to no avail

**UPDATE**

The file now looks as follows but now getting
#0 21.67 SQLServer started
#0 31.68 `/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/sqlpackage/sqlpackage: Permission denied`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS dacpac-build
ARG CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /dacpac
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "SomeName.Database.sqlproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /build -v diag
RUN dotnet tool install --tool-path /localtools microsoft.sqlpackage

FROM sql-server AS final
COPY --from=dacpac-build /localtools /tmp/sqlpackage/sqlpackage
COPY --from=dacpac-build "/build/SomeName.Database.dacpac" /tmp/SomeName.Database.dacpac

RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" && ( echo "SQLServer started" && sleep 10s ) || ( echo "SQLSERVER failed to start" && exit ) && \
    /tmp/sqlpackage/sqlpackage \
    /Action:Publish \
    /TargetServerName:. \
    /TargetDatabaseName:SomeNameDB \
    /TargetUser:sa \
    /TargetPassword:$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD \
    /SourceFile:/tmp/SomeName.Database.dacpac \
    && pkill sqlservr
```

Comment: It's important to understand that you're building multiple Docker images in this Dockerfile and switching between them. At the time you're trying to invoke `sqlpackage` you're currently on the SQL Server image, but the package is installed in the `build` image. Have you tried to `FROM build` before invoking `sqlpackage`?

Comment: Perhaps a bigger issue to deal with is that `sqlpackage` is on one image while SQL Server is in another image and not network-accessible. You may need to install `sqlpackage` inside the SQL Server image itself to achieve what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, I've been fiddling around with the Dockerfile and I think I'm starting to better understand its make up. I've gotten around the  `/bin/sh: 1: /home/mssql/localtools/sqlpackage: not found` issue but I'm now getting 

#0 21.67 SQLServer started
#0 31.68 /bin/sh: 1: /tmp/sqlpackage/sqlpackage: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the problem step by step. Follow the code and explantion given in [this blog by Ken Muse](https://www.atmosera.com/blog/automating-sql-server-2019-docker-deployments/). SqlPackage needs to be installed separately.

As quoted in blog:

> Switching to root is required when running apt-get to install packages, adjusting the ownership of folders, or performing other operations which required elevated privileges. In this case, the Dockerfile is installing dependencies that are required for sqlpackage

code from blog:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

# Elevate to root to install required packages
USER root
RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install unzip libunwind8 libicu55 -y

# Install SQLPackage for Linux and make it executable
RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2113331 
&& unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage 
&& chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage 
&& chown -R mssql /opt/sqlpackage 
&& mkdir /tmp/db 
&& chown -R mssql /tmp/db
```